# Как изобразить оператор C# await с использованием языка ДРАКОН?

Tags: c#

Как вызов `var b = await a();` изобразить с использованием языка ДРАКОН?

Comment: точно также как и любую другую синхронную операцию.

Comment: А я правильно понимаю, что в языке ДРАКОН неттакой конструкции языка как await?

Comment: В языке ДРАКОН насколько я вижу используются только успевшими стать классическими конструкции, поэтому придётся либо честно изображать полностью машину состояний (и это будет капец громоздко) либо придумать какое-то своё краткое обозначение (и это будет нестандарт).